# CSS display properties are breaking when using with wildcards

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, render

This code breaks the CSS and display the CSS code on rendered HTML page in chrome(version 74.0.3729.157) while it works fine in IE11.

```
* {display: inline-block}
```

Comment: Could you please add your code to the Codepen or al least give a link on your webpage with the issue?

Comment: Could you please add your code in Snippet.

Comment: That's usual, all the tags are renderable, including `<head>`, `<script>`, `<style>` etc. If you make them `display: inline-block`, they will become an inline-block

Answer (score 0):

If you have directly copied and pasted the code from your CSS then the above code is missing semi-colon (;), after the property is defined. Other than that I don't see a reason  why its breaking for you, unless you provide us with the complete code.

```
*{display:inline-block;}
```

Hope this helped you answer your query.

Comment: In a CSS declaration list, the semi-colon is a declaration separator, not a declaration terminator, so the "missing" semi-colon is a non-issue.

Answer (score 0):

It seems universal selector `*` is not allowing to add `display:block` there is nothing wrong in your code or missing any text but you can not add it in `universal selector`.

```
Disallow universal selector
```

You can test it on this URL.

[codebeautify](https://codebeautify.org/cssvalidate)